# How to make three columns all the full height of the page?

Tags: css

I have a page set up with 3 columns: a main content div, and a shadow/border on either side.

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/rfPJC/

I need the "shadow" divs on either side to go to the bottom of the page. How can I do this?

Example HTML

```
 <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="left"></div>
        <div id="main">
            <div id="content"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="right"></div>  
    </div>
```

Example CSS

```
html, body {height: 100%;}
#wrapper {height: 100%;}
#left {background: #555; width: 30px; height: 100%; float: left;}
#main {background: #999; width: 300px; float: left;}
#content {height: 2000px;}
#right {background: #555; width: 30px; height: 100%; float: left;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I give the sides a container... like this:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="sides_container">
            <div id="left">Left Banner</div>
            <div id="right">Right Banner</div> 
            <div id="main">
                <div id="content">Hello</div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Then CSS like this:

```
html, body {height: 100%}
#wrapper {height: 100%}
#sides_container{width:360px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; background:#555;}
#left {background: #555; width: 30px; height: 100%; float: left}
#main {background: #999; width: 300px; margin-right:auto; margin-left:auto;}
#content {height: 2000px}
#right {background: #555; width: 30px; height: 100%; float: right;}
```

I like centered as well, sorry...
http://jsfiddle.net/uhJHF/

Answer (score 1):

If the "shadow" divs have `position: fixed`, they will stay at 100% height.  However, this can obscure part of the content, and the right-shadow will align to the left.  To fix this, make the `left` value of the right div equal to the width of both divs combined, and add a left margin to the main div.

http://jsfiddle.net/rfPJC/